# Como decir "have (o have not) heard from him" en español

Tags: traducción, modismos

Let's say I want to say "as of today, I have not heard from him". As of today would be "desde hoy", but how would I translate "heard from him". It's a bit of a "modismo" or idiomatic expression I feel like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"As of today" could be sometimes translated as "desde hoy", but most times it should be "hasta hoy" or better "hasta ahora" or "hasta el momento", meaning from last times until today or until the present moment.

"Heard from him" literally is "oído desde él", but it should be translated as "sabido de él", meaning "recibido noticias sobre él" (get news about or from him).

So, **the whole phrase "As of today, I have not heard from him" could be translated as "Hasta ahora no he sabido nada de él".**

Example:

- Mary, how is going your divorce?
- As of today, I have not heard from him; he has not asked for the divorce documents, he has not sent me the money for the childs.

Spanish:

- Mary, ¿cómo va tu divorcio?
- Hasta ahora no he sabido nada de él, no ha preguntado por los papeles del divorcio, ni ha enviado dinero para (la manutención de) los niños.

In positive:

- Last week I have heard from him: he has sent me the divorce documents.

Spanish:

- He tenido noticias de él en la última semana: me ha enviado los papeles del divorcio.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an easier way to translate the sentence, using the same approach as in [Blas Soriano's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12955/12637). First of all, in your example "as of today" must be translated as "a día de hoy". And given that the action is located in the present, you can use the present tense:

> As of today, I have not heard from him.
>
> *A día de hoy no sé nada de él.*

This can be translated as "right know I know nothing of him". You can use the present also in the following example:

> I have not heard from him in a while.
>
> *Hace tiempo que no sé nada de él.*

Using the present tense sounds more natural for me than *he sabido*, although that option is also valid. Also in questions:

> Have you heard something from him?
>
> *¿Sabes algo de él?*

But maybe not in affirmative:

> Yes, I have heard that he is going to marry again.
>
> *Sí, he sabido que se va a volver a casar.*
>   *Sí, me he enterado de que se va a volver a casar.*

This is possible because in Spanish the verb *saber* can be used to express that you have a certain knowledge (now) as well as for referencing the moment you got that knowledge.